# Error linking thrift server c++

Tags: c++, thrift

I'm trying to build a thrift server in c++ but i seem to be having a problem with the linking stage. Can anyone shed any light?

Here's what i'm running. (forgive me being a c++ n00b):

```
g++ -Wall -L/usr/local/lib  user_constants.o user_types.o UserService_server.o -lthrift
```

And here's the output

```
user_types.o: In function `UserCollection::read(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*)':
user_types.cpp:(.text+0xaba): undefined reference to `CollectionInformation::read(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*)'
user_types.o: In function `UserCollection::write(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*) const':
user_types.cpp:(.text+0xca7): undefined reference to `CollectionInformation::write(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*) const'
UserService_server.o: In function `UserServiceProcessor::UserServiceProcessor(boost::shared_ptr<UserServiceIf>)':
UserService_server.cpp:(.text._ZN20UserServiceProcessorC2EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE[_ZN20UserServiceProcessorC5EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE]+0x33): undefined reference to `vtable for UserServiceProcessor'
UserService_server.cpp:(.text._ZN20UserServiceProcessorC2EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE[_ZN20UserServiceProcessorC5EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE]+0xaf): undefined reference to `UserServiceProcessor::process_getById(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
UserService_server.cpp:(.text._ZN20UserServiceProcessorC2EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE[_ZN20UserServiceProcessorC5EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE]+0x136): undefined reference to `UserServiceProcessor::process_save(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
UserService_server.cpp:(.text._ZN20UserServiceProcessorC2EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE[_ZN20UserServiceProcessorC5EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE]+0x1bd): undefined reference to `UserServiceProcessor::process_destroy(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
UserService_server.cpp:(.text._ZN20UserServiceProcessorC2EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE[_ZN20UserServiceProcessorC5EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE]+0x23e): undefined reference to `UserServiceProcessor::process_search(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
UserService_server.cpp:(.text._ZN20UserServiceProcessorC2EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE[_ZN20UserServiceProcessorC5EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE]+0x2bc): undefined reference to `UserServiceProcessor::process_searchByName(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
UserService_server.cpp:(.text._ZN20UserServiceProcessorC2EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE[_ZN20UserServiceProcessorC5EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE]+0x33a): undefined reference to `UserServiceProcessor::process_searchByEmailAddress(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
UserService_server.cpp:(.text._ZN20UserServiceProcessorC2EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE[_ZN20UserServiceProcessorC5EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE]+0x3b8): undefined reference to `UserServiceProcessor::process_checkUsernameExists(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
UserService_server.cpp:(.text._ZN20UserServiceProcessorC2EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE[_ZN20UserServiceProcessorC5EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE]+0x436): undefined reference to `UserServiceProcessor::process_registerUser(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
UserService_server.cpp:(.text._ZN20UserServiceProcessorC2EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE[_ZN20UserServiceProcessorC5EN5boost10shared_ptrI13UserServiceIfEE]+0x4b4): undefined reference to `UserServiceProcessor::process_verifyUser(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
UserService_server.o: In function `apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::writeMessageBegin(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, apache::thrift::protocol::TMessageType, int)':
UserService_server.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift8protocol16TBinaryProtocolTINS0_9transport10TTransportEE17writeMessageBeginERKSsNS1_12TMessageTypeEi[apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::writeMessageBegin(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, apache::thrift::protocol::TMessageType, int)]+0x27): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::VERSION_1'
UserService_server.o: In function `apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::readMessageBegin(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, apache::thrift::protocol::TMessageType&, int&)':
UserService_server.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift8protocol16TBinaryProtocolTINS0_9transport10TTransportEE16readMessageBeginERSsRNS1_12TMessageTypeERi[apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::readMessageBegin(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, apache::thrift::protocol::TMessageType&, int&)]+0x48): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::VERSION_MASK'
UserService_server.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift8protocol16TBinaryProtocolTINS0_9transport10TTransportEE16readMessageBeginERSsRNS1_12TMessageTypeERi[apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::readMessageBegin(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, apache::thrift::protocol::TMessageType&, int&)]+0x53): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::VERSION_1'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You might have to provide some of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build line looks a bit 'thin.' Are you sure that you're picking up all the locations of the libraries using `-L` and the libraries themselves using `-l` ?

Looking at the above, I'd say Boost and Apache are the culprits. Do you have to link them in seperately? Also, remeber than on some architectures, it's expected that the library path variable (usually `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) needs to be set to the paths on your build command line *at link time* as well as runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Usual thrift generates three .cpp file for each interface (*.thrift) you should add all of them ( UserService.cpp and UserService_constants.cpp, UserService_types.cpp ) to g++ arguments.